# What's causing this InvalidSignature exception? (public key and signature are created by PHP and the verification is done in Python)

Tags: php, python, openssl, rsa, public-key

I'm basically trying to create a signature using "openssl" (PHP) and verify that using "criptografy" (PYTHON). And I'm always getting the error "InvalidSignature", which means I'm doing something wrong. I know that they are different languages and libraries but once I'm using the same algorithm for both I expected to get a valid signature. I appreciate any help.

## PHP: creating public key and signature without problems

```
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha256",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];
error_log($pubKey);
```

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAtXyDj9vqTGkR/ITYZ6+e
>   xXATzalUOdBcqee+qcb5NJ6Z5DgNdYi9lWz/4YfitYKp0EFwPzbem1zBzKbuQSko
>   y7zRjpmyGbw8Q6wexO4SyA44jxs75JNXMA2x22dkNKajRE5kXngBIF1ixpzCxvvc
>   kfyewM8C8y2iAy5j02YZYw9ysrQWJegamq6sidnMCJBtokOnPQaNJwbDQTqwrSRS
>   8IDy7BtBHB7F/bBwLArwxG7aLFjJ9vf2F7HpmZ3VvJa69OhY0pZMSqePQpJBIQ+2
>   ztIywpKkOukJz22Brqoe0ygMQzVrcYoj2MZ8CSiKUCJL6Wm9ErFXvBh/XqPWjX1t
>   nWdnF6qSD/2itIw18+PzCWYaoeu6w064dcbRrUQ4UOYxp69IFtrv5OHAsuWPJ27q
>   2IUCZ9DWWphlwhz+lI4rAb6whd2R8Sb7vEhvSz4Kd5kIjel9Dt8mJ+jGyhTjqIhP
>   7amgcOQLKZJfmeltYI+F0U8oJcOPhxtlxfFB1MIxPDHvCcdR93LJGgU6NboTwcpx
>   hnoI86xKblJmnxMxuQbUfPRU8vAuiizKVrpQS8z2k58mlxa9+hykjMcqpAvQ6STM
>   vLswdj0j9aqyv6I94z2Q2Lgcuoh7xSJcLhKN9QGaarUqjAY/zoZPiDnCxXlnVrav
>   BMyQZ9PqbsaHsd7pVVpuW8MCAwEAAQ==
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

```
$data = 'oi';
$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($privKey);
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);
error_log(base64_encode($signature));
```

> 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

## PYTHON: InvalidSignature error

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend  
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding  
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes  
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key  
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_public_key
signature= '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'

decoded = base64.b64decode(signature)

plaintextMessage="oi"

# /tmp/public contains the public key
alicePubKey = load_pem_public_key(open('/tmp/public', 'rb').read(),default_backend())  

ciphertext = alicePubKey.verify(  
    decoded,  
    plaintextMessage,  
    padding.PSS(  
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),  
            salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH,  
    ),  
    hashes.SHA256()  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty clear that your PHP code:

1. Signed using RSA with SHA1, *not* SHA256
2. Used PKCS#1 version 1.5 padding, *not* PSS

It looks like you just copy&pasted your code from the [cryptography package documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#verification).

Thus the following python snippet should verify:

```
ciphertext = alicePubKey.verify(  
    decoded,  
    b'oi',  
    padding.PKCS1v15(),  
    hashes.SHA1()  
)
```

PSS and SHA-256 are better choices, so you should investigate modifying your PHP code to use those instead of modifying your python code.

Answer (score 0):

As James said, the function `openssl_sign` was using SHA1 by default, what could be solved with the parameter `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256`.

So I did these changes:

#### PHP

```
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

#### Python

```
ciphertext = alicePubKey.verify(  
    decoded,  
    plaintextMessage,  
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    hashes.SHA256()  
 )
```